# Wordpress AJAX load more check end of posts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

My AJAX load more function doesn't check end of posts properly - it shows preloader one more time if there are no posts. This is caused by removing pleroader's hidden class every time before send ajax request.

How should I check end of posts correct?

**AJAX**

If response is 0 - just hide the preloader. So preloader is shown one more time when it shouldn't be.

```
    var page = 3;
    var emptyQuery = false;
    function load_posts() {
        page++;

        var category = $('.cat-list__item.active').data('category');
        $.ajax({
            url: flow.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
                $('body').addClass('loading');

                if ($('.preloader').length) {
                    $('.preloader').removeClass('preloader--hidden');
                }
            },
            data: {
                action: 'scroll_post_load',
                page: page,
                category: category

            },
            success: function (response) {
                if ( response==0 ) {
                    emptyQuery = true;
                    if ($('.preloader').length) {
                        $('.preloader').addClass('preloader--hidden');
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($('.preloader').length) {
                        $('.preloader').addClass('preloader--hidden');
                    }

                    var html = response;
                    $(html).hide().appendTo('.posts-list').fadeIn(1000);
                }

                $('body').removeClass('loading');
            }
        });
    }

    // Scripts which runs on scrolling
    $( window ).on( 'scroll', function() {
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('.posts-list').height() && !$('body').hasClass('loading')) {
            if(emptyQuery == false) {
                load_posts();
            }
        }
    } );
```

**PHP**

If it is the last page - returns 0 in response

```
function scroll_post_load(){
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];

    if( $category=='all' || !$category ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => '3',
            'paged' => $paged
        );
    }
    if( $category ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => '3',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'cat'   => $category
        );
    }

    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages == get_query_var('paged')) {
        return '0';
    }

    if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
            show_template('loop-post');
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_scroll_post_load', 'scroll_post_load');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_scroll_post_load', 'scroll_post_load');
```

Comment: Check `emptyQuery` before making request

Comment: @charlietfl it is actually checked. I've added the code displaying that below AJAX function. The problem is I can set `emptyQuery` only after get empty AJAX response. But preloader is anyway shown `beforeSend` request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this if you just return in your response what is the total number of pages and then in the script check if next page is last or something.

That's how I do it usually. I always return the max number of pages along with the content so I can check if I need to execute the AJAX call one last time.

Comment: Could you please tell how do you pass varible with max number of pages along with pages content? I do echo posts template to show them. But how can I pass variable from PHP to JS?

Comment: I assume this function show_template('loop-post') is echoing the content.

You can do the following:

ob_start()
show_template('loop-post');
$content = ob_get_clean();

$max_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

$result = [ 'content' => $content, 'max_pages => $max_pages];

wp_send_json( $result );

Then in the ajax success you can have the content
var html = response.content;
max_pages = response.max_pages;

Have max_pages var outside of the function and then check if the next page is the last page.

Comment: After the page++ you can do the followin:

if ( page > max_pages ) { 
return 
}

This way the code won't be executed again